# Why does if ( 'a'<= /*some char*/ <= 'z') not work?

Tags: c#

I have been taking an online course in C# and, while solving one of the tasks I came across this:

I needed to write a piece of code which determined if the first letter of a word is found between 'A' and 'F', so I wrote the following if statement:

```
string command= Console.ReadLine();    
if (('a' <= command[0] <= 'f') || ('A' <= command[0] <= 'F'))
```

And gave me the following error:
    "Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'char'"

So, after a lot of head scratching I replaced it with this:

```
  if (('a' <= command[0] && command[0] <= 'f') || ('A' <= command[0] && command[0] <= 'F'))
```

And that worked just fine, but I can't figure out why the first one didn't work. 
Can someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you split

```
'a' <= command[0] <= 'f'
```

into its components (as the compiler would see it), you get

```
Stage 1:  'a' <= command[0]
Stage 2: (result of stage 1) <= 'f'
```

So, the 2nd half of the original statement becomes:

```
 true <= 'f'
```

which is obviously the error you are seeing

Answer (score 4):

The compiler interprets

```
'a' <= command[0] <= 'f'
```

as if it were written like

```
('a' <= command[0]) <= 'f'
```

Answer (score 1):

In most languages you are not able to chain comparisons like that in a boolean expression.

The second works because you are breaking it down into one comparison at a time.

Valid:
`a < b`
`a < b && a < c && b < c`

Invalid:
`a < b < c`